# Return an instance of an inner class from a static method in Java

Tags: java

**The following are user requirements which I cannot change:**

1. A class with a static interface (all methods are static).
2. One specific method returns an `ArrayList<String>` object and a `File` object.

**The following is my implementation of the above requirements:**

1. An inner class which contains an `ArrayList<String>` object and a `File` object.
2. The specific method initializes an instance of the inner class and returns it at the end.

But I am unable to create an instance of the inner class without creating an instance of the outer class:

```
public class Outer
{
    public class Inner
    {
        ArrayList<String> strings;
        File              file;
    }

    public static Inner method()
    {
        Inner inner = new Outer().new Inner();
        ...
        return inner;
    }
}
```

Besides being "ugly", the `new Outer().new Inner()` feels pretty incorrect.

Is there a different approach that I can take in order to avoid having to instantiate the outer class?

Comment: It is bad design to nest classes that are used elsewhere. Consider separating them. Straight from Oracle, "_[Nesting] is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place: If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined._"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make the inner class static (that is, you write `public static class Inner`) then you don't need an instance of the outer class; you can just write `new Outer.Inner()`.

Comment: That simple??? Man... I should have tried that to begin with (had it in my head, but couldn't see why it would help); thanks